# How to align with view element present in the included layout in Android

Tags: android-layout, android

I would like to align the view element in the current layout with the view element which I included through  tag in Android.

Layout1: (Layout1.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/click_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_click" />

    <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:text="@string/textview1"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="@string/textView2"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/includedLayout"
        layout="@layout/Layout1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/seperator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:alpha="0.3"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <!-- I want to align this layout with relative layout present in the 
        Layout1.xml file which is included above -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to align the second LinearLayout in the Layout2.xml with the RelativeLayout in the Layout1.xml file which is included in the Layout2.xml file.

Please let me know if anyone knows the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to align that linear layout with the text views? Can you be more clear

Comment: Want to align the second LinearLayout in Layout2.xml file with the RelativeLayout in the Layout1.xml file [Code above pasted is just an example, this RelativeLayout can contain more views other than just text views].

Answer (score 0):

whay dont you try putting the layout part that you want to align in to another file and only include that file in to the your layout2.xml and manually coding remining part in the layout2.xml.
What i mean is to take
`

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:text="@string/textview1"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/textView2"
    />
</RelativeLayout>`
```

this part in to another separate file and manually add imageview in to layout2.xml

Comment: Thanks, but the purpose of re-use goes away :), I want to reuse including image view.